# Can I set the colour of text when adding strings to an empty div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, arrays, colors

I am currently working on a networked multiplayer game and my current method of writing out the list of players is to add the strings from an array to an empty  using jQuery.

My code looks like this:

```
var html = '';
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    html += (i+1) + ". " + data[i] + '<br/>';
}
$players.html(html);
```

This all works but I want to set the colour of each string individually. As in, the first line would be black, then the second line would be red, then the third line would be blue, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wrap each string in another tag eg...

```
<p>string</p>
```

You can then set either the class attribute or style attribute on that tag individually. eg. 3 suggested options...

```
<p class="line2">string</p>
<p class="red">string</p>
<p style="color:red">string</p>
```

If the lines should be consistently coloured, I would personally use the "class" option, as it allows you to set each style just once.

EDIT: I just realised you also want to know how to do discrete values for each iteration inside the loop. For this, I would first create an array of style names or color values, and then apply them using the same index position as the array you are looping through. To save you having to define a color array guaranteed to be at least as long as your player array, you could loop through the same color list using the modulo (remainder) operator "%" eg...

```
var colors = ["black", "red", "blue"];
var html = '';
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    html += "<p style='color:" + colors[i % 3] + "'>" + (i+1) + ". " + data[i] + '</p>';
}
$players.html(html);
```

This will apply color[0] to line 0, color[1] to line 1, color[2] to line 2, and then wrap around to color[0] for line 3.

To save having to modify the modulo value ("3") whenever your color list changes, a further enhancement would be to replace `colors[i % 3]` with `colors[i % colors.length]`.

Comment: `<p>` tags come with their own inherient styling.  You would want to use `<span>` if you only want the color change.

Comment: Agree that `<span>` is perfectly valid, but it has no semantic meaning. I personally prefer to use semantic markup whenever possible because it helps accessibility. TBH, the best semantic choice here would be an ordered list (ie. `<ol><li>...</li></ol>`), but that was outside the scope of the question and would have complicated my answer unncecessarily. Any inherent styling of semantic markup always can (and should) be reset as desired.

Comment: @Rooksword - Please remember to accept one of the answers, to support those who supported you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Obviously you can change the colors and their order anytime.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var data = ['Bob','Smith','John','Jackson','Michael','Steve'];
  var colors = ['red','blue','green','orange'];
  var html = '';
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    html += '<p style="color: '+ colors[i%colors.length] + ';">' + (i+1) + ". " + data[i] + '</p><br/>';
  }
  $('.players').html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="players"></div>
```